# how to do the scatter plot for the lists or 2d array or matrix python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

```
 X=[[0,3,4,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,5,1,1],
    [6,7,0,8,1,1],
    [3,6,1,5,6,1]]

Y=[12,15,11,10]
```

I have the lists how to do the scatter plot to visualize the X , Y to check that relationship??

Comment: What do you want on your x and y axis? Do you want all 6 lines on the same plot?

Comment: I am considering do the least square such as the equation  A *[0,3,4,0,1,1]+k= 12,   A *[0,0,0,5,1,1]+k=15.....But , I am not sure what is the relationship between X and Y , whether it is linear or not. I would like to show the dots in the same plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your X being in the wrong orientation, I'm using a numpy array to easily transpose it. Then it's just a matter of plotting it on the same axis, changing the colors so you can see what's what.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_arr = np.array(X)
y = np.array(Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colors=list('bgrcmykw')

for i, x in enumerate(x_arr.T):
    ax.scatter(x,y, c=colors[i])

plt.show()
```

[image]